# How to create a responsive subivew based on the minimise or drag the window for Mac OS X application?

Tags: macos, autolayout

I am trying to create an Mac OS X application and this application should be responsive based on the user minimise and drag of the window. I have tried using the auto lay out and was partially successful in doing that. This is what i have followed.
I have added the constraints for auto layout as http://tinypic.com/r/2v2ukqc/8. But if i minimising the width of the window the subview is minimising the width shown in the following http://tinypic.com/r/30ky2ht/8. Can any one guide me how to set the minimum size for the subview to get minimised. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by adding the width constraint and setting it greater than and lesser than.